# 3 color ball problem

Tags: random

I have essentially infinite number of balls, ⅓ each of 3 colors. How many must I blindly draw to be 95% confident I have 1 or each color? I think the answer is 11, but I'd like the equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is 11?  Can you please add the work you did to get to 11 in your post?  That is what we expect a quality question post to do. And that will help us focus our feedback.

Comment: Suppose that you draw exactly $5$ balls.  What is the exact probability that the $5$ balls do not contain at least $1$ of each color?  Suppose that the $3$ colors are red, blue, green.  What is the probability that (for example) neither of the 1st $2$ balls drawn are red?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it looks like you are going to have to be concerned about Inclusion-Exclusion.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Comment: To answer Bram28: This problem was solved many years ago, I can't recall it correctly. As I recall the left side of the equation began "1-alpha = ", alpha representing the confidence interval or 0.95. So the equation was determining the 0.05 chance that the balls drawn did not contain all three colors. The equation did not involve combinations, or factorials. I recall the equation, once solved, being something like 10.43???, meaning I had to select 11 balls.

Comment: Response to user2661923: I recall the answer was a straightforward equation, nothing with all those set functions. It just had (1-n)^⅔ * (1-n)^⅓.  or something like that. Something that even I could solve with algebra

Comment: @geneticist Consider $$\frac{N}{D} ~: D = 3^n$$ and $N$ is the number of choices possible, (where order of selection is regarded as pertinent), and where, after $n$ selections, there are at least one of each of the $3$ colors.  Let $S_1,S_2,S_3$ denote the respective ways of choosing $n$ items, that are missing a Red ball, Green ball, or Blue ball, respectively.  Then $N = D - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3|.$ ...see next comment

Comment: For this particular problem, this approach is extremely painless: see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.