# Number of possible combinations of X numbers that sum to Y where the order doesn't matters

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, summation, combinations, integer-partitions

I am looking for the number of possible outcomes given to a set of numbers X that sum to Y. This is the same issue as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462099/number-of-possible-combinations-of-x-numbers-that-sum-to-y?newreg=b015449b96784c55be18caccce5df45f). However, I would like to consider that (i) the numbers can't be repeated and (ii) the order doesn't matter. For example, the only possible outcome for:

- 4: [3,1] given the list [3,2,1]
- 5: [[4,1],[3,2]] given the list [4,3,2,1]

An implementation in Python with the possible answers is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193555/finding-combinations-to-the-provided-sum-value) (Answer 2), If a list with ascending or descending order without repetitions is passed the problem is the same as the examples above. However, what I want is just the possible number of answers.

Comment: Let $S$ is set of numbers of cardinality $n$, $X_i$ are elements of set $S$, such that $X_1>X_2 > \ldots > X_n$, let $S_i$ is set of $X_j$ with $j>i$. Then $N(Y,S)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} N(Y-X_i,S_i)$, $N(0,\emptyset)=1$, $N(Y,\emptyset)=0$ for $Y>0$.

Comment: Maybe, for numerical calculations it is better to use reverse indexing. Let $S_n$ is set of numbers of cardinality $n$, $X_i$ are elements of $S_n$ such that $0 < X_1 < X_2<\ldots X_n$, let $S_i$ is set of $X_j$ with $j\leq i$, $S_0=\emptyset$. Then $N(Y,S_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n N(Y-X_i,S_{i-1})$, $N(0,\emptyset)=1$, $N(Y,\emptyset)=0$ for $Y>0$.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are two distinct viable (analytical) approaches, both of which are discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445581/how-many-combinations-of-4-digits-0-9-have-a-sum-of-10-with-no-repeats/4446250#4446250).  In the linked answer, there is the trivial difference of the solutions being in strictly ascending order.  The real challenge, which is addressed in the linked answer, is eliminating *solutions* where two or more of the variables have the same value.

Comment: Re my previous comment, to a certain extent, this is different from the OP's problem in that I am specifically assuming that if the desired sum is $T$, that the set in question is $\{0,1,2,\cdots,T\}.$  **However**, it may be feasible to **convert** a problem like find all solutions where the set is $\{1,3,4,5\}$ to a similar problem where the **adjusted** set is $\{0,1,2,3\}.$

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that cannot be computed easily. Even deciding if the number of solutions is greater than 0 is known as the subset sum problem which is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), so finding the exact number of solutions is at least as hard.

If the set is small, simply trying all subsets could be a solution, and for larger sets otherwise, there are other algorithms, eg. [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-all-solutions-to-the-subset-sum-problem-597f77677e45).

Comment: Analytical approaches are possible.  See my comment, following the original posting.  To a certain extent, this is different from the OP's problem in that I am specifically assuming that if the desired sum is $T$, that the set in question is $\{0,1,2,\cdots,T\}.$