# Possible 4-digit numbers using ${1,2,3,4,5}$ under constraints.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many 4-digit numbers can be crafted from $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ under the following conditions:

$1$ can not appear two or more times ($1142$) is not valid 
$2$ can not appear three or more times ($2242$) is not valid 
$3$ can not appear 4 times ($3333$) is not valid

With $4$ and $5$ there are no conditions. The thing is that a number can not appear more than its value say. That's why with $4$ and $5$ there are no conditions.

Obviously, 3204 is not valid.

After this condition, how could I compute the number of possible 4-digit numbers?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Is $5555$ valid?  Regardless of the details, Inclusion Exclusion seems indicated.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it is. I've edited the body to be more clear.

Comment: So, when you say that, for example, $1$ can only appear $1$ time, you meant "$1$ can not appear more than $1$ time".  Ok.  As I say, Inclusion Exclusion ought to work.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll change it.

Comment: @lulu could you give me a tip or a hint? I don't know how to start

Comment: Usual Inclusion Exclusion.  Start with the total (no restriction).  subtract those that violate (at least) one restriction, add back those that violate at least two, subtract those that violate at least three.  And so on.

Comment: Should say, it's not particularly difficult to do this directly.  Let $(a,b,c,d,e)$ denote the number of $1's$, $2's$, etc in your string.  Thus $a+b+c+d+e=4$.  Now just list the allowable $5$-tuples and count the number of strings you can with each.  A bit tedious, but there really aren't many allowable $5-$ tuples.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.  When considering how many $4$ digit numbers there are, that ignore the constraints, there are $5$ choices for each digit.  Therefore, the starter enumeration is $\displaystyle ~(5)^4.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using EGF, compute by pen and paper.

The EGF of 1's: $e^{x}-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!}$

The EGF of 2's: $e^{x}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!}$

The EGF of 3's: $e^{x}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!}$

The EGF of 4's, 5's: $e^{x}$

We get EGF:

$G\left ( x \right )=\left ( e^{x}-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!} \right )\left ( e^{x}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!} \right )\left ( e^{x}-\frac{x^{4}}{4!} \right )e^{2x}$

The desired number is the coefficient of $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ term in the expansion of G(x):

$\left [ \frac{x^{4}}{4!}\right ]G\left ( x \right )=\left [ \frac{x^{4}}{4!} \right ]\left ( e^{x}-\frac{x^{2}}{2!}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!} \right )\left ( e^{x}-\frac{x^{3}}{3!} \right )e^{3x}-3=\left [ \frac{x^{4}}{4!} \right ]\left ( e^{5x}-\frac{x^{2}e^{4x}}{2!}-\frac{x^{3}e^{4x}}{3!}-\frac{x^{3}e^{4x}}{3!}\right)-3=5^{4}-6\cdot4^{2}-2\cdot4\cdot4^{1}-3=\boxed {494}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There are $T = 5^5 = 3125$ possible combinations without conditions. Calculate how many combinations violate the conditions and substract from $T$.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to extract all $4$ digit permutations from $1223334444555555$

An alternative to inclusion-exclusion is to use generating functions to find the coefficient of $x^4$
in $4!(1+x)(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!})(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!})^2$

$(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})$, eg represents $2$ occurring $0,1\; or\; 2$ times. Note that $x^2, x^3, x^4$ have been divided by $2!,3!,4!$ respectively to get the correct number of permutations. Also, $5$, too, has been restricted to $4$ repetitions because the word is only $4$ letters long.

I get an answer  of $494$, but you should check.