# Permuting the digits of a 6 digit number with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to permute the digits of the number 123456 such that:

$n$ is not the $(n+1)$th digit for $1\leq n\leq 5$ and 6 is not the 1st digit.

I am not sure about how I should approach the problem without using some ugly casework. If there is an alternative method could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?  What have you tried?

Comment: You are looking for derangements of "612345"

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.  Following the syntax of the 2nd link, I suggest letting $S_k$ denote the subset of numbers where $k$ is located in the $(k+1)$ digit place, thus violating the constraint.