# Counting with triple intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm self learning math (and English as well, plz forgive my bad English). While reseaching I found this rule:

If A, B and C are three finite sets then:

n( A ∪ B ∪ C ) =
n(A) + n(B) + n(C) – n( A ∩ B ) – n(B ∩ C) – n(A ∩ C) + n( A ∩ B ∩ C )

I cannot find any explaination about this rule. Could you help to prove this equation (maybe explain by Venn diagram)? Another question, why the last element is `+ n( A ∩ B ∩ C )` but not `- n( A ∩ B ∩ C )` (since in the case of two sets, we have `n( A ∪ B ) = n(A) + n(B) - n( A ∩ B )`)

Comment: See [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: If you count the elements of A and add those of B you will count twice the common elements. This explain the two-sets case. Similar for the three-sets case...

Comment: It can help to build intuition if you look at a venn diagram where each region is individually labeled.  For example [this one](http://cstl-cla.semo.edu/hhill/pl120/notes/venn_8_regions.GIF) (*not the greatest image, but first I found*).  Using the labeling on the image, note that $n(S) = n(1)+n(2)+n(4)+n(5)$, that $n(P)=n(2)+n(3)+n(5)+n(6)$, that $n(S\cup P\cup M) = n(1)+n(2)+\dots+n(7)$, and so on... You will find that if we were to just add $n(S)$ and $n(P)$ we will have added $n(2)$ and $n(5)$ too many times since they were both a part of $S$ and $P$. The formula you cite cancels correctly

Comment: Extending to many sets, you will find that you will alternate between subtracting and adding (*and then subtracting again and then adding again etc...*) the pairs, triples, quadruples etc... of intersections of sets.  This can all be formally proven by induction.  Recognize that $(A\cup B\cup C) = (A\cup B)\cup C$, and that $(A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_n\cup A_{n+1}) = (A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n)\cup A_{n+1}$

Comment: Thank you both of you, now I understand

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.