# Coupon Collector's Problem Probability - Why $-1$?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

The formula shown below can be used to calculate the probability of not collecting all $m$ coupons after $k$ trials in a coupon collector's problem (with $m$ coupons). Could you please explain us something about the "$-1$" in the formula below? Where does it come from and what it is the intuition behind it?

$$p = \sum^{m}_{i=1} (-1)^{i+1} {m \choose i} \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^k$$

Comment: If you read any proof for that formula (or prove it yourself), it should be explained there.

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion Formula u known?

Comment: @Arthur I went searching.  I found numerous articles that discuss the expected number of coupons selected after $k$ trials, or the expected number of trials required to get all coupons.  However, I couldn't find any article that was directly on point re the OP's question.  Also interesting that (unless I am mistaken) the OP's formula is wrong : see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please explain us something about the "−1" in the formula below? Where does it come from and what it is the intuition behind it?
> $$p = \sum^{m}_{i=1} (-1)^{i+1} {m \choose i} \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^k$$

For what it's worth, I am posting this answer because my research into the Coupon Collector's problem has failed to find this exact problem addressed.

> The formula shown below can be used to calculate the probability of not collecting all m coupons after k trials in a coupon collector's problem (with m coupons).

I may be misinterpreting the OP's (i.e. original poster's) intent.  I am interpreting the problem to be that you have $m$ coupons, and that you randomly select $k$ coupons, one at a time, **with replacement.**

I am assuming that $k \geq m.$

Also, unless I am mistaken, the correct formula is

$$p = \sum^{m}_{i=1} (-1)^{i+1} {m \choose i} \left(\frac{m-\color{red}{i}}{m}\right)^k.$$

Inclusion Exclusion is used.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

For any set $E$, with a finite number of elements, let $|E|$ denote the number of elements in the set $E$.

For the specific problem, let $S$ denote the collection of all **multisets** that represent all possible distributions of the $m$ coupons, where each set contains $k$ elements, and a specific element (i.e. collected coupon) can occur more than once.

For $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}$, let $S_i$ denote the subset of $S$ that contains all multisets that are missing coupon $i$.

Then, the desired computation is

$$\frac{|S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_m|}{|S|} ~: ~|S| = m^k.$$

Let $T_1$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq m} |S_{i_1}|.$

Let $T_2$  denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq m} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2}|.$

That is, $T_2$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{m}{2}~$ terms.

Similarly, for $~3 \leq r \leq m,~$ let $~T_r~$ denote the $~\displaystyle \binom{m}{r}~$ terms given by

$~\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq m} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r}|.$

Then, in accordance with Inclusion Exclusion Theory,

$$|S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_m| = \sum_{r=1}^m (-1)^{r+1} T_r.$$

Thus, the entire problem has been reduced to showing that

$$T_r = \binom{m}{r}\left(m-r\right)^k. \tag1 $$

---

To enumerate $T_r$, first consider the specific computation of

$|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \cdots \cap S_r|.$

There are $(m-r)^k$ ways that $k$ coupons can be collected from the subset of coupons represented by $\{r+1, r+2, \cdots, m\},~$ where the sampling is done with replacement.

Further, by considerations of symmetry, for any ordered $r$-tuple 
$(i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_r) ~: ~i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r,$ 
you have that 
$|S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r}|$ 
is also equal to $(m-r)^k.$

So, in computing $T_r$, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{m}{r}~$ ways of selecting the $r$ coupons that will be missing.

So, the formula in (1) above is established.

It is important to note that (for example)
in the subset of distributions represented by 
$S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \cdots \cap S_r$, 
while the coupons represented by $\{1,2,\cdots,r\}$ are missing in each such distribution, other coupons may also be missing from the represented distributions.

In fact, it is this consideration that :

- Promotes the easy computation of $~\displaystyle \binom{m}{r} \times (m-r)^k.$
- Requires that Inclusion Exclusion be used.

For example, consider the situation where the coupons that are represented by $\{1,2\}$ are missing, and no other coupons are missing.

Such distributions will be counted twice.  Once in $|S_1|$ and once in $|S_2|$.  Then, these distributions will be deducted once because of the term $|S_1 \cap S_2|$, which is part of the computation of $T_2$.

So, the **net** effect is that such coupons are counted $~(+2 - 1) = 1~$ time.

Comment: many thanks for your excellent reply.