# How to determine the number of $4$-digit numbers that do not contain the sequence $17$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm working on this:

Determine the number of 4-digit numbers that do not have the sequence 17. Eg 47113 an allowed 5-digit number, 1572 an allowed 4-digit number but 1723,3175,0254 are not allowed.

I'm stuck on how to find the probability of finding 17 in the number.

Comment: Do you know the inclusion/exclusion formula?

Comment: As suggested by @Nick, this problem can be conquered by a simple application of Inclusion-Exclusion.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Answer (score 3):

There are 9000 4 digit numbers

To count the ones containing `17`
take cases:

```
17XX - 100 cases
Y17X - 90 cases
YX17 - 90 cases

X is 0-9.  Y is 1-9
```

don't forget to subtract 1 for the double counted number `1717`

Comment: I sumbmitted this answer and it was not correct. Any suggestions why? Put in 8719.

Comment: WW1 says 9000-100-90-90, so 8720. He says that we substract 1717 twice, when substracting 17xx, and xx17. So final count is 8720+1=8721.