# How to solve combination question with restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics

I've n pair of couples where w pair doesn't wish to be paired together. How can I get the number of combinations (male & female pair) using a formula?

Example for 3 pair where 2 pair (number 1 and 2 couple) doesn't wish to be paired together and 1 pair either way (number 3 couple). The following has 3 combinations.

M1 - F2, M2 - F1, M3 - F3
M1 - F3, M2 - F1, M3 - F2
M1 - F2, M2 - F3, M3 - F1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like an instance of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderBurstein Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Comment: Re last comment, my first instinct would be to index the couples as $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_w, b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{n-w}.$  Then, I would let $S$ denote the set of all possible couplings, where each couple has 1 man and 1 woman.  Then, I would let $S_k$ denote the subset of S, where couple $a_k$ are together.  Then, you can apply the Inclusion-Exclusion theory in my last comment.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be $n$ couples, $k$ of whom do not want to be paired. Then by inclusion/exclusion the number of possible pairings is
$$\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom ki(n-i)!$$
The terms that are alternately added and subtracted, $(n-i)!$, count the number of pairings where $i$ of the "forbidding" couples are paired anyway. This can happen in $\binom ki$ ways, since the forbidding couples are fixed.

In your instance $n=3$ and $k=2$, and the formula gives $3$ admissible matchings, agreeing with your explicit listing.

Comment: Thanks, I can't get 3 using the formula above. May i know how you expand it?

Comment: I consider Parcly's formula is correct, I did not check. It can be used for any values (n,k). What is your question ? Do you need explanation about some symbols ?

Comment: @Gab I checked myself and it did give $3$...

Comment: Hi @Lourrran, just wondering (n-1)! is kCi formula?

Comment: @Gab It's just a factorial.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel correct me if I am wrong, (-1)**0 * (3-0)! + (-1)**1 * (3-1)! + (-1)**2 * (3-2)!

Comment: @Gab it's $1×3!-2×2!+1×1!=3$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks, just confused about where you get the -2 from −2×2!. According to the formula it's (-1) to the power of i, hence isn't it (-1) power 1 = -1?

Comment: @Gab There's an extra $\binom ki$ factor that gives that $2$.