# Counting passwords of length $8$ requiring special characters, numbers, uppercase, and lowercase letters?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to count passwords of length $8$ requiring at least one of all of the following: digit, special character, uppercase letter, lowercase letter. There's $10$ digits, $15$ special characters, $26$ uppercase letters, and $26$ lowercase letters.

**My approach:**

Answer $=$ Total number of passwords $-$ Passwords without special character $-$ Passwords without uppercase letter $-$ Passwords without lowercase letter

Since there's $10+15+26+26=77$ total characters That's:

$$77^8-(77-10)^8-(77-15)^8-2(77-26)^8 \approx 5.198\cdot 10^{14}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Inclusion-Exclusion is not that simple.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

---

For any set $~E~$ with a finite number of elements, let $~|E|~$ denote the number of elements in the set $~E.$

- Let $~S~$ denote all of the passwords possible, if the requirements of digits, special characters, upper case letters, and lower case letters are ignored.
- Let $~S_1~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that violates the constraint that at least one digit must be present.
- Let $~S_2~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that violates the constraint that at least one special character must be present.
- Let $~S_3~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that violates the constraint that at least one lower case letter must be present.
- Let $~S_4~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that violates the constraint that at least one upper case letter must be present.

Then, the desired computation is

$$|S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4|. \tag1 $$

- Let $~T_0~$ denote $~|S|.$
- For $~r \in \{1,2,3,4\},$ 
  let $~T_r~$ denote $\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 4} | ~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r} ~|.$ 
  That is, $~T_r~$ denotes the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{r}~$ terms.

Then, in accordance with Inclusion-Exclusion theory,
the computation in (1) above equals

$$\sum_{r=0}^4 (-1)^r T_r. \tag2 $$

So, the problem reduces to computing
$~T_0, ~T_1, ~T_2, ~T_3, ~T_4.$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_0}$

There are $~77~$ choices for each of $~8~$ letter positions.

Therefore,

$$T_0 = (77)^8.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$

To compute $~|S_1|~$ note that there are $~67~$ choices for each of the $~8~$ character positions.  This is because $~S_1~$ represents the subset of $~S~$ where all digits are excluded.  This means that instead of there being $~77~$ choices for each character position, there are only $~(77 - 10) = 67~$ choices for each character position.

Therefore, $~|S_1| = (67)^8.$

Very similarly:

- $~|S_2| = (62)^8.$
- $~|S_3| = (51)^8.$
- $~|S_4| = (51)^8.$

Therefore,

$$T(1) = |S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3| + |S_4| \\
= (67)^8 + (62)^8 + (51)^8 + (51)^8.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$

Similar to the analysis in the previous section, 
to compute $|S_1 \cap S_2|,~$ you must reason that with no digits or special characters, there are $~52~$ choices for each of the 8 character positions.

Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_2| = (52)^8.$

Similarly:

- $~|S_1 \cap S_3| = (41)^8.$
- $~|S_1 \cap S_4| = (41)^8.$
- $~|S_2 \cap S_3| = (36)^8.$
- $~|S_2 \cap S_4| = (36)^8.$
- $~|S_3 \cap S_4| = (25)^8.$

Therefore,

$$T_2 = (52)^8 + (41)^8 + (41)^8 + (36)^8 + (36)^8 + (25)^8.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_3}$

$|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| = (26)^8,~$ 
since this represents the set where only capital letters are used in each of the $~8~$ character positions.

Similarly:

- $|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_4| = (26)^8.$
- $|S_1 \cap S_3 \cap S_4| = (15)^8.$
- $|S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4| = (10)^8.$

Therefore,

$$T_3 = (26)^8 + (26)^8 + (15)^8 + (10)^8.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_4}$

$S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4 ~$  represents the set of all 8 character sequences with no digits, special characters, lower case letters or upper case letters.

Therefore, $~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4 = \emptyset.$

Therefore,

$$T_4 = 0.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$T_0 = (77)^8.$$

$$T(1) = (67)^8 + (62)^8 + (51)^8 + (51)^8.$$

$$T_2 = (52)^8 + (41)^8 + (41)^8 + (36)^8 + (36)^8 + (25)^8.$$

$$T_3 = (26)^8 + (26)^8 + (15)^8 + (10)^8.$$

$$T_4 = 0.$$

The expression in (1) above equals

$$T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3 + T_4.$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Okay, reasonable criticism.  I edited that portion of my answer to make my intent more clear.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Answer edited.

Comment: I love how nicely this is layed out. I'm familiar with Inclusion/Exclusion but was it wasn't entirely obvious to me that I should use it. But it does make sense because subtracting off passwords not including numbers for example also subtracts away some passwords that are missing capital letters, etc, so we need to add that back in, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you have not applied inclusion-exclusion correctly.

Let $D,S,U,L$ represent missing digit, special character, upper case, lower case, respectively.

Then "bad" passwords are

$\small|D|+|S|+|U|+|L|$

$\small - \{\;|D\cap S| +|D\cap U| +|D\cap L| +|S\cap U|+ |S\cap L| +|U\cap L|\;\}$

$\small + \{\;|D\cap S \cap U| + |D\cap S \cap L| + |D\cap U\cap L|+|S\cap U\cap L|\;\} $

[All $4$ types can't be missing together]

Subtract from total possible passwords.

Comment: I think $\small + \{\;|D\cap S \cap U| + |D\cap S \cap L| + |S\cap U\cap L|\;\} $ is missing a $|D\cap U\cap L|$. Is that right?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins: yea, sorry, was working on mobile. Corrected