# A simple PIE prob

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In how many ways can we seat $5$ pairs of twins in a row of $10$ chairs such that nobody sits next to his or her twin ?
To count the number of possible arrangements with PIE it's simple to calculate the no. of ways in which we can seat $1$ pair of twins to be $9!.2.5$ but how to calculate the the ways in which we can seat more than $1$ pair of twins? For $2$ pair of twins it is ${5\choose{2}}.2^2.8!$ but it's getting messy for more pairs so is there any general way.

Comment: What is PIE ?...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @JeanMarie PIE=principle of inclusion and exclusion

Comment: $$10! + \sum_{i=1}^5 \left[ ~(-1)^i ~\binom{5}{i} 2^i ~(10-i)! ~\right].$$  $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{i} ~$ reflects picking which $~i~$ pairs will violate the constraint.  $~2^i~$ reflects internally permuting the $~i~$ pairs.  $~(10-i)! ~$ reflects permuting the $~(10-i)~$ external units.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.