# In how many ways can we seat 5 pairs of twins in a row of 10 chairs, such that nobody sits next to his or her twin?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

This was a problem from the AOPS Intermediate Probability and Counting book, from a chapter on Principle of Inclusion Exclusion (PIE). I was able to follow the solution, but don't understand why PIE applies to the problem.

Essentially, they find the number of ways to seat exactly 1-5 pairs of twins together, and use PIE to calculate the number of ways that at least 1 pair of twins is together, and subtracts it from the total number of ways with no restriction.

So they do #ways-pair1 - #ways-pair2 + #ways-pair3 - #ways-pair4 + #ways-pair5

However, why does PIE work for this? When I think of PIE I think of venn diagrams and sets. The formula for PIE with n sets is basically sum (alternating sign) of the nth elementary symmetric sums, but intersecting instead of multiplying.

What would the sets in this problem be?

Comment: Let $~S~$ denote the set of all possible seatings, without any regard for whether twins are together.  Label the pairs of twins T-1, T-2, T-3, T-4, T-5.  For $~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ such that the pair of twins T-k are together.  Then, you want $$|S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4 \cup S_5|.$$  For illustration purposes: clearly $~|S| = 10!,~$ and $~|S_1| = 2 \times 9!.$ ...see next comment

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.  Using the syntax in the second link, you would have $$T_0 = |S| = 10!, ~T_1 = |S_1| + \cdots + |S_5| = 5 \times 2 \times 9!.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets, which you have called pair$n$, are the number of ways to seat the people so there are at least $n$ pairs next to each other.  The point is that if you have exactly $2$ pairs seated next to each other you have counted the arrangement twice in pair$1$ so need to subtract one.  If you have $3$ pairs seated next to each other you have counted the arrangement three times in pair$1$ and added them, then counted it three times in pair$2$ and subtracted them, so you need to add it in once and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I can gather, the *set* that you're interested in is a *subset* of $^{10}P_{10} = 10!$. *Venn diagram*atically, the set that you're interested is a circle *inside* the circle for $10!$

The PIE *technique* seems to *overcount* by first calculating $10!$ and then *subtracting* what was overcounted to leave you with the correct answer.

By the way do the calculations involve the numbers 9, 2, 90, and $8!$? Just curious.
Have a good day.