# Probability of Flipping A Coin Ten Times and Tails Occur Only in Pairs

Tags: probability

Suppose a coin is flipped
10 times and the outcomes are recorded. Find the probability that any tails occur only in consecutive pairs. For example, with
4 flips,
TTHH and
HHHH are both valid, but
HTHH and
TTTH are not valid.
I know that I'm supposed to use inclusion-exclusion principle, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Comment: Can you clarify whether $TTTT$ is valid?  In other words, as long as there are an even number of tails can they be consecutive?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add up sequences of "doubles" and "singles",
eg (in order doubles-singles), $5-0,4-2,\,...\,0-10$, thus

$$\dfrac{\frac{5!}{5!0!} + \frac{6!}{4!2!} + \frac{7!}{3!4!} + \frac{8!}{2!6!}+\frac{9!}{1!8!} + \frac{10!}{0!10!}}{2^{10}} = \frac{89}{1024}$$

Comment: Is the answer clear ?

Comment: Small typo, it should be $6!$. Answer is $\frac{89}{1024}$

Comment: @LéoAparisideLannoy: Thanks, typo fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Markov Chain Solution:

- Define $A$ the event: "The current sequence has an even (including 0) number of T".
- $B$ is the event: "The current sequence has an ood number of T"

We have:

$$
P_k(A) = \frac{1}{2}(P_{k-1}(B)+P_{k-1}(A)) \\
P_{k}(B) = \frac{1}{2} P_{k-1}(A)
$$
Stacking the probabilities in a vector $A_k=(P_k(A),P_k(B))$, we have:

$$
A_k= \frac{1}{2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} A_{k-1}
$$
We have $A_1=(.5,0.5)$ and using the recursion:
$$
A_k= \frac{1}{2^9} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^9 A_{0}
$$
We find $P_{10}(A) = \frac{89}{2^{10}}$