# Why can't I use a direct approach in the birthday problem?

Tags: probability, birthday

In a variation of the birthday problem, we are trying to find the probability that another student in the class shares our birthday. We can use the complement rule to find the probability that a student does not share the same birthday as us.

```
P(S) = 1 - P(*S) = 1 - (P(*S1) * P(*S2))
```

Can’t we find the probability of having the same birthday as us and add up to the number of students, i.e

```
P(S) = P(S1) + P(S2)
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

For example, with two students, the Complement method

```
1 - ((364/365) * (364/365)) = 0.005471945956089
```

Direct method

```
1/365 + 1/365 = 2/365 = 0.005479452054795
```

With 100 students
Complement method = 0.2399329261841
Direct method = 0.273972602739726

The answers are different.

Can someone clarify what I am missing here?

Comment: Consider what happens with $366$ students, for example.

Comment: Yes, but why does this approach fail ?

Comment: The birthday problem is not that someone shares YOUR birthday, but that two people share the same birthday.  If the first person has a different birthday than you there is a new birthday added to the list we can match. This makes it more likely to occur as you miss.

Comment: Yes, but this is a reduced version of the problem. This problem is specifically asking if someone else shares our birthday.

Comment: The probability at least one of two students shares you birthday is the probability the first does and the second does not, plus the probability the second does and the first does not, plus the probability they both do.  So $\frac{1}{365}\times\frac{364}{365} + \frac{364}{365}\times\frac{1}{365} + \frac{1}{365}\times\frac{1}{365}$ $=\frac{1}{365}+\frac{1}{365}-\frac{1}{365^2}$.  Your "direct approach" is too high because it overcounts cases where more than one person shares your birthday and this effect gets bigger as you have more other students.

Comment: It's clear now, thanks!

Comment: FYI i believe you have stated the birthday problem incorrectly. do you want the probability that at least any two people have the same birthday or the probability that anyone else shares $your$ birthday?

Comment: Its a variation of the birthday problem. It asks the probability of at least one person having the same birthday as us.

Answer (score 0):

The direct approach, although not recommended, is do-able, via Inclusion-Exclusion.  This approach provides a remedy to the issue of over-counting raised by the comment of Henry.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Let $~Q~$ denote the set of all possible distributions of the birthdays of the $~n~$ people, without any regard for whether any of the people share a birthday with you.

Let $~S~$ denote the subset of $~Q~$ where at least one person shares a birthday with you.

Then the desired computation of the probability is

$$\frac{|S|}{|Q|} ~: ~|Q| = (365)^n,$$

So, the problem reduces to computing $~|S|,~$ which represents the number of elements in the set $~S.$

---

Index the $~n~$ people $~P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n.$

For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ let
$~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ such that person $~P_k~$ shares a birthday with you.  For example, $~S_1~$ represents the set of all possible birthday distributions, where person $~P_1~$ shares a birthday with you, and any of the other people may or may not share a birthday with you.

Then, since $~( ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_n ~) = S,~$ the problem reduces to computing

$$| ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_n ~|.$$

---

Let $~T_1~$ denote $ ~|S_1| + |S_2| + \cdots + |S_n|.$

For $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,n\},~$
let $~T_r~$ denote

$\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq n} | ~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r} ~|.$

That is, $~T_r~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}~$ terms.

Then, in accordance with Inclusion Exclusion theory,

$$| ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_n ~| 
= \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r+1} T_r.$$

So, the problem reduces to computing $~T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_n.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$

$S_1~$ represents the set where $~P_1~$ shares your birthday, and all of the other people are unrestricted.

Therefore, $~|S_1| = (365)^{n-1}.~$

By Symmetry, for each $~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,n\},~$ you have that $~\displaystyle |S_k| = |S_1|.~$

Therefore,

$$T_1 = \binom{n}{1} (365)^{n-1}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$

$( ~S_1 \cap S_2 ~)~$ represents the set where $~P_1~$ and $~P_2~$ both share your birthday, and all of the other people are unrestricted.

Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_2| = (365)^{n-2}.~$

By Symmetry, for each 
$~1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n ~: ~i_1, i_2 \in \Bbb{Z},$ 
you have that
$~\displaystyle |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2}| = |S_1 \cap S_2|.~$

Therefore,

$$T_2 = \binom{n}{2} (365)^{n-2}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_r ~: 3 \leq r \leq n}$

The analysis in this section will parallel the analysis of the previous section.

There will be $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}~$ terms,

and each term will equal $~(365)^{n-r}.$

Therefore,

$$T_r = \binom{n}{r} (365)^{n-r}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$\forall r \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}, ~T_r = \binom{n}{r} (365)^{n-r}.$$

$$ |S| = \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r+1} ~T_r.$$

The probability is

$$\frac{|S|}{|Q|} ~: ~|Q| = (365)^n.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

By binomial expansion, the numerator of the final answer represents

$$(365)^n - \left[ ~365 - 1 ~\right]^n.$$

This implies that the final computation is

$$\frac{(365)^n - (364)^n}{(365)^n}. \tag1 $$

The expression in (1) above makes perfect sense, since $~(364)^n~$ represents the number of ways that the $~n~$ people can each avoid sharing your birthday.