# Find the number of three-digit integers that contain at least one $0$ or $5$. The leading digit of the three-digit integer cannot be zero

Tags: combinatorics

Here, I tried guessing possibilities of the following problem.
Consider the set $\{100, 101, \ldots, 110\}$.
All these are desirable and there are $11$ elements in this set.
Now consider $\{115, 116, \ldots, 195\}$, here if we consider the finite arithmetic progression $115,120,125,\ldots,195$ of $17$ terms, none of them is desirables.
So from $100$ to $195$ there are $28$ desirable numbers.
Similarly, from $200$ to $295$ there are $28$ desirable numbers.
Between $300$ and $395$ there are also $28$ desirable numbers.

And so on...
But every integer between $500$ and $599$ is also desirable, so there are $100$ more desirable numbers.

So we can say that the required answer would be $28 \cdot 8+100=324$.

But in answer key, the correct answer is $388$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is hard to follow your approach.  To be clear, have you remembered to include $151, 152, 153, 154,\dots$?

Comment: There are $900$ three-digit integers.  Of these $8\times 8\times 8$ have no $0$'s and no $5$'s.  Since we want the opposite, numbers that have at least one 0 or at least one 5 this gives $900 - 8^3 = 388$, requiring mere seconds to arrive at.  I feel your approach made things much harder than they needed to be, possibly taking a minute or more.

Comment: I attempted to rewrite your question in a proper form, using LaTex. Please, try to do the same for future questions.

Comment: As mentioned by JMoravitz[https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz], when you get a question, like "How many numbers are there who contain ... (**or** ...)", best is to ask yourself "How many do **not** contain?" and subtract this from the total amount.

Comment: Another approach would be to consider that there are $100$ three-digit numbers starting with a $5$, and for each digit $d \in \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$, there are $36$ three-digit numbers starting with a $d$ where at least one of the last two digits is a $0$ or a $5$. This gives $100+(8)(36)=388$ possible numbers.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang that is literally the OP's approach, but where they mistakenly thought there were 28 rather than 36 such numbers for each case (*again, because of forgetting to consider the second digit*).

Answer (score 1):

> Where did I go wrong?

"Now consider $\{115,116,…,195\}$
, here if we consider the finite arithmetic progression $115,120,125,…,195$
of $\color{red}{17}$
terms"

Wrong. Because, $\color{green}{\{151,152,153,154\}} \, \& \, \color{green}{\{156,157,158,159\}}$ i.e $8$ terms are also eligible. So. there is total $17+8=25$ eligible terms not $17$ in $\{115,116,…,195\}$.

Now, you can count $(25+11)\cdot 8+100=388$

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion Exclusion works here.

There are exactly $~900~$ numbers (i.e. elements) between $~100~$ and $~999,~$ inclusive.  Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,999\}.$

For $~k \in \{1,2,3\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the **subset** of such elements that have a [0 or 5] in column $~k,~$ of the 3 digit number.

Then, you want $~|S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3|.~$

---

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

So, the desired computation is

$$|S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3| \\
- \left\{ ~|S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3| ~\right\} \\
+ |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|.$$

Clearly $~S_3~$ which focuses on the rightmost column has $~\dfrac{900}{5} = 180~$ elements, since a number has $~0~$ or $~5~$ in its rightmost column if and only if it is divisible by $~5.~$

By symmetrical considerations, $~|S_2|~$ is also equal to $~180.~$

Similarly, since each element in $~S~$ can not have a $~0,~$ in its leftmost column, $~|S_1|~$ must equal $~\dfrac{|S|}{9} = 100.~$

Therefore, $~|S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3| = 460.~$

In considering the subset $~S_1 \cap S_2,~$ the coordination between $~0,5~$ in column-3 with $~0,5~$ in column-2 is **random**.  So, you must have that $~|S_1 \cap S_2| = |S| \times \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{5} = 36.$

Similarly, both $~|S_1 \cap S_3|~$ and $~|S_2 \cap S_3|~$ must equal $~|S| \times \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{9} = 20.$

Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3| = 76.~$

Similarly, $~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| = |S| \times \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{9} = 4.~$

Therefore, the final computation is

$$[460 - 76] + 4 = 388.$$

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is equivalent to considering three positions

$$—~—~—$$

and asking yourself how many possibilities are there where you can place digits from $0$ to $9$ in each position with the mentioned restrictions.

Well, we can't fix $0$ on the first position, but you can fix $1$ (as you did in your first and second sets), so now we have to count how many desirable possibilities are there for the other two digits with the first fixed at $1$. Well, if we fix $0$ on position two, we are left with $10$ possibilities for the last one, and each is desirable because we have at least $0$, and the same occurs if you fix $5$ ($10$ more possibilities).

$$\overset{1}{—} ~ \overset{0}{—} ~ \overset{p_3}{—} ~~~ : ~~~ 10 ~ \text{choices}$$

$$\overset{1}{—} ~ \overset{5}{—} ~ \overset{p_3}{—} ~~~ : ~~~ 10 ~ \text{choices}$$

For the rest of the choices of the middle position, we always get two desirable choices for the last one ($0$ or $5$), and since there are $8$ more such choices for the middle (we already used $0$ and $5$), we have $8\cdot 2=16$ remaining possibilities. Adding them gives $2\cdot 10+16=36$, not $28$.

Now, if you choose any other digit for the first position (other than $5$), you'll get the same number of possibilities as you got with $1$, but since $0$ is not allowed (and $5$ a special one), we have $8$ choices, and therefore $8\cdot 36=288$ possibilities.

To address $5$ in the first position is easy, because any choice of the other two digits is desirable, and we have $10$ choices for the second and third positions, totalizing $10\cdot 10=100$ possibilities when $5$ is fixed.

Adding everything gives $288+100=388$.