# How many permutations are possible in a 10 digit number containing 2 and 5 such that no two 2's are together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ten digits whole number satisfy the following property they have 2 and 5 as digits, and there are no consecutive 2's in the number (ie. any two 2's are separated by at least one 5).

So I know pretty good way of solving this question

Now let $A_n$ represent all number that can be formed following above condition for n digit number

For $A_n$ there are two possibility

Number ending in 2

_ _ _  . . . . (2/5), 5 , 2 (n digit number)

So here last 2 digit are fixed so here all permutations are equal to $A_{(n-2)}$

Number ending in 5

_ _ _  . . . . (2/5), 5 (n digit number)

So here last digit is fixed so all permutations are equal to $A_{n-1}$

Now we have the recursive relation That

$A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$(n>2)

Now

a1= 2

a2 = 3

Now we can use the recursive relation to find a10=144

But the thing is if I didn't read it I wasn't able to quite solve it without counting same cases again so is there any other way apart from this method to solve this question..

Comment: I think the recursive method is best, but if you want another method:  Note that your number can't have six $2's$ (why?).  So just count those with five $2's$, four $2's$, and so on and sum those up.   Each of those counts is a routine Stars and Bars Problem, so you can write the answer as a sum of binomial coefficients.

Comment: The recursive method shows these are Fibonacci numbers (offset) and that will probably be quicker than any other method

Comment: @Henry I agree.  However, lulu's Stars and Bars method (i.e. Method 1 in my answer) runs a close second when the # of digits $~ = 10,~$ and is (perhaps) better when the # of digits is $~\geq 25.~$  Also, inclusion-exclusion (i.e. Method 2 in my answer), while far inferior to the Stars and Bars method, still permits manual computations (as I construe them) to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse and see that the number of 2's cannot exceed 5, as then there will be atleast 1 pair of 2. If you want to explain your problem to a high schooler,you can make a event specific formula.

Say there are *n* number of 2s.Hence there are *10-n* number of 5s. Our favourable arrangement is like this

$$× 5 × 5 × 5 × 5 × 5 × ...5 × $$

where $×$ represents possible spaces where 2 can be placed

The number of empty spaces = 10-n+1

Number of 2's=n

So total number of arrangements = $$\sum_{n=0}^{5}\frac{^{(10-n+1)}P_n}{n!}$$

(n=0 for 5555555555) Dividing by $n!$ because of repitition of 2

My answer from this is coming to 144

Answer (score 1):

I just edited the Inclusion-Exclusion section (i.e. Method 2), to try to make it easier to understand.

---

Extending the comment of lulu, you know that a satisfying solution will have $~k~$ 2's, where $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,5\}.~$  There are two alternate methods that generalize well, Stars and Bars and inclusion-exclusion.

$\underline{\text{Method 1: Stars and Bars}}$

Hold $~k~$ as a **fixed constant.**

First, for Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Consider the following tableau, which assumes $~k = 3,~$ for illustrative purposes:

```
___2__2___2__
```

The placement of the $~3~$ 2's creates (k+1 = 4) islands of 5's.  Let $~x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4~$ denote the size of these islands.  Then the number of satisying placements of exactly $~3~$ 2's is exactly equal to the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = (10 - k) = 7.$
- $x_1, \cdots, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3 \geq 1.$

The idea is that with the end variables $~x_1,x_4~$ ignored, there will be no occurrence of consecutive 2's if and only if each of the other islands is of size $~\geq 1.~$

The standard adjustment here is to set

- $y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{2,3\}.~$
- $y_i = x_i ~: ~i \in \{1,4\}.$

So, assuming that $~k = 3,~$ there is a bijection between the set of solutions to the original problem, and the set of solutions to the problem

- $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_4 = (10 - 3) - (3 - 1) = 11 - (2 \times 3) = 5.$
- $y_1,\cdots,y_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.~$

For general $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,5\},~$ this conversion translates to the number of solutions to

- $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{k+1} = 11 - (2k).$
- $y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is

$$f(k) = \binom{[11 - 2k] + k}{k} = \binom{11 - k}{k}.$$

Note that if $~k~ = 0,~$ then the number of solutions is $~f(0) = \displaystyle 1 = \binom{11}{0}.$

Therefore, the final computation is

$$\sum_{k=0}^5 f(k) = \sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{11-k}{k}$$

$$= \binom{11}{0} + \binom{10}{1} + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{8}{3} + \binom{7}{4} + \binom{6}{5}$$

$$= 1 + 10 + 36 + 56 + 35 + 6 = 144.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Method 2: Inclusion-Exclusion}}$

The analysis here will be more complicated than that of Method 1, so I regard this method as somewhat inferior for this particular problem.  However, despite the complication, the method will still allow you to avoid manual computation.

First, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.  Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Following the syntax in the 2nd link in the previous paragraph, let $~S~$ denote the collection of all possible $~10~$ digit numbers, where each digit is an element of $~\{2,5\}.~$  That is, $~S~$ (also) includes those $~10~$ digit numbers that violate the constraint of no consecutive 2's.

For $~p \in \{1,2,3,\cdots,9\},~$ let $~S_p~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where the 10 digit numbers specifically contain a $~2~$ in digit positions $~p~$ and $~p+1.~$ Note that for each element in the subset $~S_p,~$ there may or may not be a consecutive 2's violation elsewhere in the 10 digit number.

Then, the desired computation is

$$|S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_9|. \tag1 $$

Let $~T_0 = |S| \implies T_0 = 2^{10} = 1024.~$

Let $~\displaystyle T_1 = \sum_{i_1 = 1}^9 |S_{i_1}| \implies T_1 = 9 \times 2^{10 - [2 \times 1]} = 9 \times 2^8 = 2304.~$

For $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,9\},~$ let $~T_r~$ denote

$\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 9} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r}|.$

That is, $~T_r~$ denotes the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{r}~$ terms.

Then, following inclusion-exclusion theory, the computation in (1) above is equivalent to

$$\sum_{r=0}^9 (-1)^r T_r. \tag2 $$

The difficulty in this method is that although symmetrical considerations facilitated the computation of $~T_1,~$ these considerations break down, for $~r > 1.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Manual Computation of} ~T_2}$

The manual way of computing $~T_2~$ is to recognize that of the $~36~$ terms involved in the computation of $~T_2,~$ you will have:

- $~|S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2}| = 2^{10 - 3} = 2^7,$ 
  if and only if $~i_1 + 1 = i_2,~$ which will occur in exactly $~8~$ of the $~36~$ terms.
- $~|S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2}| = 2^{10 - 4} = 2^6,$ 
  if and only if $~i_1 + 1 < i_2,~$ which must therefore occur in the other $~(36 - 8) = 28~$ terms in the computation of $~T_2.~$

Consequently, $~\displaystyle T_2 = \left[ ~8 \times 2^7 ~\right] + \left[ ~28 \times 2^6 ~\right].~$

The above analysis represents the **manual** computation of $~T_2.~$ What is needed is an analytical method of obtaining  a formula for $~T_r ~: ~r \geq 2.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Analytical (i.e. non-manual) Computation of} ~T_r ~: ~2 \leq r \leq 9}$

In the previous section, manual consideration was given to the $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{2}~$ terms in the computation of $~T_2,~$ in order to determine how many of these terms had $~7~$ digits unspecified, and how many of these terms had $~6~$ digits unspecified.

This section provides an analytical shortcut to the process, which may be used when computing $~T_r,~$ for any value of $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,9\}.~$

Suppose, for example that you are computing $~T_5,~$ and consider the specific intersection of $~(P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_4 \cap P_5 \cap P_9).~$  The following tableau represents this intersection:

```
 ____i-1=1____i-2=2____i-3=4____i-4=5____i-5=9____
```

The variables $~i_1, \cdots, i_5~$ are assigned the digit positions that correspond to the violation subsets that they represent.  These $~5~$ digit positions create $~(5 + 1)~$ islands.

Let $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_6,~$ denote the size of these islands.  Then, you have that $~(x_1, \cdots, x_6) = ~(0,0,1,0,3,0).~$  Note that in this example, there are exactly $~2~$ variables from the set $~\{x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\},~$ that are equal to $~0.~$  Note further that the specific intersection of $~(P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_4 \cap P_5 \cap P_9)~$ will leave exactly $~[ 10 - (2 \times 5) + 2 ~] = 2 ~$ digit positions unspecified, digit positions $~7~$ and $~8.$

In fact, in any selection of $~5~$ sets to be intersected, from the collection of sets $~\{P_1, \cdots, P_9\},~$ if the intersection causes exactly $~w~$ of the variables $~x_2, \cdots, x_5~$ to equal $~0,~$ then the number of digit positions left unspecified will be $~[ ~10 - (2 \times 5) + w ~].$

This is because each of the variables $~x_2, \cdots, x_5~$ that equals $~0,~$ represents a *compressed* intersection, that involved only $~3~$ digit positions, rather than $~4~$ digit positions.

This analysis generalizes to the characterization of any term in the computation of $~T_r,~$ for any value of $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,9\}.~$ That is, if among the variables $~x_2,\cdots, x_r,~$ exactly $~w~$ of them are equal to $~0,~$ then the number of unspecified digit positions will equal $~[ ~10 - (2 \times r) + w ~].$

Therefore, you have that

$$T_r = \sum_{\text{min value for} ~w}^{\text{max value for} ~w} \\   \left[ ~\text{# of intersections that yield}  ~w ~\text{zeroes} ~\right] ~\times 2^{[ ~10 - (2 \times r) + w ~]}$$

For any value of $~r,~$ since there are $~(r-1)~$ variables represented by $~x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_r,~$ the variable $~w~$ must be some element in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots, (r-1) \}.$  So, $~(r - 1)~$ will always be the maximum allowable value for $~w.~$ Stars and Bars analysis will be used to derive the general formulas, in terms of $~r,~$ for the minimum allowable value of $~w,~$ and the $~\# ~$ of intersections that yield $~w~$ zeroes among the variables $~x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_r.$

---

Notice that the total size of the $~(r+1)~$ islands combined, plus the number of intersections, $~r,~$ must equal $~9.$  Therefore, you will always have that $~x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r + x_{r+1} = (9-r).$

Let $~r~$ be some **fixed** element in $~\{2,3,\cdots,9\},~$ and assume that among the variables $~x_2, \cdots, x_r,~$ exactly $~w~$ of these variables are equal to $~0.~$

Then, in the computation of $~T_r,~$ the $~\#~$ of intersections that yield exactly $~w~$ zeroes will exactly equal the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{r+1} = 9 - r.~$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{r+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- Exactly $~w~$ of the variables $~x_2~$ through $~x_r~$ inclusive, are equal to $~0.~$

To enumerate the above problem, the first thing to notice is that there are $~\displaystyle \binom{r-1}{w}~$ ways of selecting the $~w~$ variables from the set $~\{x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_r\}~$ that will equal $~0.~$

So, reserve the factor $~\displaystyle \binom{r-1}{w},~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the first $~w~$ variables from the set $~{x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_r}~$ represent the variables that are set to the value $~0.~$

Then, exclude these $~w~$ variables from consideration, and re-index the remaining $~(r+1 - w)~$ variables, in ascending order, adopting the variable names $~z_1~$ through $~z_{(r+1 - w)}.~$

Then, the above problem bijects to enumerating the number of solutions to

- $~z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_{(r+1 - w)} = (9 - r).~$
- $~z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_{(r+1 - w)} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- For $~w < (r-1), ~z_2, \cdots, z_{r-w}~$ are each $~> 0.~$

At this point, you can employ the same standard method that was employed in Method 1.

That is, adopt the change of variables $~y_i = z_i~$ for $~i \in \{1,(r+1-w)\},~$ and for each variable $~z_i~$ such that $~2 \leq i \leq (r-w)~$ (if any), set $~y_i = z_i - 1.~$

So, the above enumeration problem bijects to enumerating

- $~y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_{(r+1 - w)} = (9 - r) - [(r-w) - 1] = 10 + w - 2r.~$
- $~y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{(r+1 - w)} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Since each of the variables $~y_1, \cdots, y_{(r+1 - w)}~$ is a non-negative integer, the minimum allowable value for the expression $~(10 + w - 2r)~$ is $~0.~$ Therefore, $~w~$ must be $~\geq (2r-10).~$ Therefore, the lower bound for $~w~$ is $~\max[ ~(2r - 10), ~0 ~].$

By Stars and Bars theory, for a fixed value of $~r,~$ and a specific value of $~w~$ that is between its lower and upper bounds, the enumeration of the number of solutions, [ignoring the reserved factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{r-1}{w} ~$] is

$$\binom{[10 + w - 2r] + [r - w]}{r - w} = \binom{10 - r}{r - w}.$$

Therefore, for each $~r \in \{2,3,\cdots,9\},~$

$$T_r = \sum_{w = \max\left[ ~(2r - 10), ~0 ~\right]}^{r-1} \left[ ~\binom{r-1}{w} \times ~\binom{10 - r}{r - w} \times 2^{(10 - 2r + w)} ~\right]. \tag3 $$

---

$~\underline{\text{Final Computation For Method 2}}$

The number of $~10~$ digit numbers, where each digit is an element in $~\{2,5\}~$ and there is no occurrence of any consecutive 2's is

$$\sum_{r = 0}^9 (-1)^r T_r,$$

where:

$$T_0 = 2^{10} = 1024.$$

$$T_1 = 9 \times 2^8 = 2304.$$

Then, employing the formula in (3) above:

$$T_2 = \sum_{w = 0}^1 \left[ ~\binom{1}{w} \times \binom{8}{2 - w} \times 2^{6 + w} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~1 \times \binom{8}{2} \times 2^6 ~\right] + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{8}{1} \times 2^7 ~\right] = 2816.$$

---

$$T_3 = \sum_{w = 0}^2 \left[ ~\binom{2}{w} \times \binom{7}{3 - w} \times 2^{4 + w} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~1 \times \binom{7}{3} \times 2^4 ~\right] + \left[ ~2 \times \binom{7}{2} \times 2^5 ~\right] + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{7}{1} \times 2^6 ~\right]= 2352.$$

---

$$T_4 = \sum_{w = 0}^3 \left[ ~\binom{3}{w} \times \binom{6}{4 - w} \times 2^{2 + w} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~1 \times \binom{6}{4} \times 2^2 ~\right] + \left[ ~3 \times \binom{6}{3} \times 2^3 ~\right] + \left[ ~3 \times \binom{6}{2} \times 2^4 ~\right] $$

$$+ \left[ ~1 \times \binom{6}{1} \times 2^5 ~\right]= 1452.$$

---

$$T_5 = \sum_{w = 0}^4 \left[ ~\binom{4}{w} \times \binom{5}{5 - w} \times 2^w ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~1 \times \binom{5}{5} \times 2^0 ~\right] + \left[ ~4 \times \binom{5}{4} \times 2^1 ~\right] + \left[ ~6 \times \binom{5}{3} \times 2^2 ~\right]$$
$$+ \left[ ~4 \times \binom{5}{2} \times 2^3 ~\right]  + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{5}{1} \times 2^4 ~\right]= 681.$$

---

$$T_6 = \sum_{w = 2}^5 \left[ ~\binom{5}{w} \times \binom{4}{6 - w} \times 2^{w - 2} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~10 \times \binom{4}{4} \times 2^0 ~\right] + \left[ ~10 \times \binom{4}{3} \times 2^1 ~\right] + \left[ ~5 \times \binom{4}{2} \times 2^2 ~\right] $$
$$+ \left[ 1 \times ~\binom{4}{1} \times 2^3 ~\right] = 242.$$

---

$$T_7 = \sum_{w = 4}^6 \left[ ~\binom{6}{w} \times \binom{3}{7 - w} \times 2^{w - 4} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~15 \times \binom{3}{3} \times 2^0 ~\right] + \left[ ~6 \times \binom{3}{2} \times 2^1 ~\right] + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{3}{1} \times 2^2 ~\right] = 63.$$

---

$$T_8 = \sum_{w = 6}^7 \left[ ~\binom{7}{w} \times \binom{2}{8 - w} \times 2^{w - 6} ~\right]$$

$$ = \left[ ~7 \times \binom{2}{2} \times 2^0 ~\right] + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{2}{1} \times 2^1 ~\right] = 11.$$

---

$$T_9 = \sum_{w = 8}^8 \left[ ~\binom{8}{w} \times \binom{1}{9 - w} \times 2^{w - 8} ~\right] = 1.$$

---

So,

$$\sum_{i = 0}^9 (-1)^r T_r$$

$$= (T_0 + T_2 + T_4 + T_6 + T_8) - (T_1 + T_3 + T_5 + T_7 + T_9)$$

$$=(1024 + 2816 + 1452 + 242 + 11) - (2304 + 2352 + 681 + 63 + 1)$$

$$= 144.$$

Comment: I really appreciate your answer Steve, you always elaborated in each answer. I think it is because of the discipline of old generation (+1)